# grails - scafold update prevent from saving

Tags: grails, scaffolding

I'm using grails 2.4.4 and default update method generated by scaffolding. Let's say it is:

```
@Transactional
def update(Club clubInstance) {
    if (clubInstance == null) {
        notFound()
        return
    }

    if (clubInstance.hasErrors()) {
        respond clubInstance.errors, view:'create'
        return
    }

    clubInstance.save flush:true

    request.withFormat {
        form {
            flash.message = message(code: 'default.created.message', args: [message(code: 'clubInstance.label', default: 'Club'), clubInstance.id])
            redirect clubInstance
        }
        '*' { respond clubInstance, [status: CREATED] }
    }
}
```

I would like to prevent saving under some circumstance. But I found out that I could replace whole method with:

```
@Transactional
def save(Club clubInstance) {
    redirect action:"index"
}
```

And it still saves data. Only if I remove `Club clubInstance` from arguments it stops to save data to db. Could anyone tell me why it happens and how can I control saving?

Comment: It's because OSIV (open session in view) is flushing the instance to the database. Discard it using `clubInstance.discard()` in your method before you redirect.

Comment: Calling `discard` isn't the right solution.  If all he wants the `save` action to do is redirect to `index`, then simply remove the `Club clubInstance` parameter from the `save` method and leave the `redirect` as shown in his example.  There is no reason to retrieve the object and do data binding if all you are going to do is discard the changes.

Comment: If the scenario involves conditionally issuing the redirect (which isn't shown in the example code), then the `discard` might make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for comments. It is what I want - conditional saving.

```
@Transactional
def save(Club clubInstance) {
    if(testSomeCondition())
        clubInstance.save flush:true
    else
        clubInstance.discard()
    redirect action:"index"
}
```